# Python encrypt a string using an alternate alphabet

Tags: python, string, encryption

I'm unsure on how to make this work. I need to encrypt a string given a different alphabet.

```
def substitute(string, ciphertext):
    alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    encrypted = []
    list(alphabet)
    list(ciphertext)
    encrypted = ""
    for x in string:
        if x.isalpa():
            encrypted.append(ciphertext[x])
        else:
            encrypted.append(x)
            word = string.join(encrypted)
    print(encrypted)

    return encrypted
```

Comment: What precisely is not working? Can you include an example of expected input and output.

Comment: Not encryption, encoding.  The more you know...

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
def substitute(string, ciphertext):
    alphabet = list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ") # list() returns a list,
    ciphertext = list(ciphertext) # it doesn't change (mutate) the variable
    encrypted = [] # Not sure why you were storing the empty string here,
                   # but strings cannot use the append() method.
    for x in string:
        if x.isalpha(): # Fixed a typo
            # Here I think you want to use alphabet.index(x) instead of x.
            encrypted.append(ciphertext[alphabet.index(x)])
        else:
            encrypted.append(x)
    return "".join(encrypted) # Turning the list into a string
```

As the other commenter said, in the future please add examples of what you do and don't what your code to do.

I would suggest looking up the definition of ***mutability*** since that seems to be what you are struggling with.